# How to make a correction, similar correction curves in Photoshop for Java

Tags: java, android, image-processing

How to color correct the curves in Java(Android)? Is there such a possibility using the standard libraries, in particular, OpenGL? Can someone help me where to start from?

Answer (score 0):

Android Documentation: `AntiAliasing smooths out the edges of what is being drawn, but is has no impact on the interior of the shape...`

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawCircle(center_x, center_y, radius, paint);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I'm looking for something like this: http://www.photocolorcorrection.com/graphics/curves.gif
Such correction algorithm, or any library.

Comment: Sorry but I am not familiiar with Photoshop.